# Make text scrollable within div

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, scrollable

I am looking to make some lengthy text contained into a `div` where the text can be viewed by scrolling up or down. 
Right now the "description" text is rendered like so `<%= @pin.description.html_safe %>` and is inside a `<div class="panel-body>` (I'm using **Bootstrap**).

Comment: you can add `panel-body some-class` and style `.some-class` with `max-height: 100px; overflow-y: auto`;

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Give your `div` a height and set `overflow: scroll`

```
#elementId{
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

If you only want it to scroll up/down and not left/right use:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Vtcgy/)**